# Writing to csv does not work when using time module

Tags: python, csv, time, keyboard

I try to save 1's to csv file but wheb I use time module nothing is saving and moves.csv file is empty, but when I use the same code without time.sleep(1) everything is working. Does anybody have any idea what might be wrong?
Thanks for Your time!

```
import time
import keyboard

with open('moves.csv', 'w') as f:
  while True:
    if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
      f.write('1\n')
      time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Are you holding down the space key, or just pressing it briefly?

Comment: I am using it to save actions while playing google dino, so pressing briefly while jumping i guess.

Comment: With `sleep(1)` in the loop, it would have to be depressed at the exact moment `if_pressed` is called, which only happens once per second.

Comment: The problem is when I do not use sleep, it saves like 10 spaces per one click, but I want to map one frame to one key so I need 1-1 mapping not 1-10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file is written to a buffer which only gets written to disk when the OS decides; commonly, when you `close` the file, or the buffer fills up.

To see the file grow in real time, try writing a larger amount of text in each iteration.

Comment: I tried with a larger text, but still file is empty while I use time.sleep and when I do not use it then the same text is written to a file like 200 time. It seems like a very basic task, but I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: Try terminating the script which writes the file; that should flush it. You can also explicitly `.flush()` without closing.